# Eclipse ou android studio?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

Estou utilizando o *Eclipse*, mas me deparei com o `android studio`, há alguma razão para mudar?

Comment: Melhor em que sentido? Dessa forma a sua pergunta vai ser fechada como baseada em opiniões. Consegue editar a perguntar, modificando seu corpo, para que a mesma não seja fechada por esse motivo?

Comment: em utilizar os recursos do programa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio, o Google não fornece mais suporte ao ADT (plugin do eclipse para desenvolver android), logo o ADT tende a não suportar as novas APISs do Android (que atualmente esta na evisão 22).